# Sql query manipulation for individual records in by group

Tags: sql, sas

I am new to sql, please help.
I have a table
like:

```
ID  account bad amount 
1   100      1   1000
1   10001    0    0
2   211      0    0
2   21101    1   700
2   21102    0    0
5   123      0    0
5   12301    0    0
5   12302    1    100
3   111      0    0
3   11102    0    0
4   1213     1   600
4   121302   1   700
```

The output i want to get is:

```
ID account bad amount
1    100    1  1000
2    21101  1  700
4    1213   1  600
```

The rule here is that: for a ID, it can have mulptile account(parent account, and sub accounts which is parent account id plus '01' or '02' or '03'....). parent account is the one does not end with '01' or '02 or '03'. so for an ID, it is defined as bad (bad = 1)

```
1) if its parent account is bad
2) else if sub account is bad with amount > 500
3) for parent account and sub account both are bad, take parent account.
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The site however is not a code for free service. If you want help with your own code you should show us what your have done so far (either code or research at least) and we can direct you from there.

Comment: Are you using `proc sql` or a particular database?

Comment: This is probably accomplished more efficiently with a data step.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for this using a PROQ SQL procedure but I don't know how to do this. However, I have wrote some code using a data step that may be of some use.

Hope this helps;

```
proc sort data=input_dataset;
    by ID;
run;

data step1;

    set input_dataset;

    account2 = compress(put(account,8.));
    length_acc = length(compress(put(account,8.)));
    if length_acc >= 2 then 
        last_two = substr(account2, length_acc-1, 2);

    if last_two IN ("01", "02", "03") then
        parent_acc = "N";
    else parent_acc = "Y";

    if parent_acc = "Y" and bad = 1 then
        score = 0;

    else if parent_acc = "N" and bad = 1 and amount >= 500 then
        score = 0;

    else score = 1000;

run;


proc sort data=step1;
    by ID score descending parent_acc;
run;


data step2;
    set step1;
    by ID;
    if first.ID and score = 0 then
        output;
    keep ID account bad amount;
run;
```